# Python Latin-1 Supplement to decimal

Tags: python, character-encoding, decimal, iso-8859-1

with python

```
ord('a')
```

gives

```
 97
```

but

```
ord('é')
```

gives an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found
```

How to get the decimal for other letter than ASCII (é = 233) like in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Latin-1_Supplement?

Comment: What python version are you using? I tried the same in python 2 and 3, both worked fine.

Comment: I had the same problem with Python 2.7.9, but worked fine in Python 3.4.2

Comment: In order to reproduce, you need a file which is encoded in UTF-8 but *lacks* the `encoding: utf-8` comment.  This I believe should only affect Python 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decode it first:

```
ord('é'.decode('utf-8'))  # outputs 233
```